# WinRT c# compiled to exe but does not run outside visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-runtime, exe, winrt-xaml

Hey all I am pretty new to the "old" WinRT (Windows Runtime) framework and I am unsure about one thing so far. How do I run the app outside of Visual Studio? In Visual Studio when ran using "Local Machine" it compiles and runs just fine. However, if I try the .exe that it produces outside of Visual Studio then nothing happens - no error and no app screen...

Like I said, in Visual Studio it compiles and runs:

[image]
[image]

So when I go and execute the NitroCarEntertainmant.exe outside of Visual Studio then nothing happens. What am I missing that seems to be something that it needs to run? I know a store app has a extension of .Appx so not sure if I have to package it up in some way or if this .exe can work - I just don't know how to make it work myself - with some type of trick/hack/bypass?

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: WinRT "alone" is an API. You don't need a package to use it (well, let's say in general...), but are you using an UWP ("Universal Windows") app (terminology has gone crazy over these last years) ? If yes, you need packagind (aka: deploy) to run it, you can't just start the .exe.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a package and install it before running. On Windows 8 and 8.1 you'll need a developer license for this but on Windows 10 you can install it normally however you added to sign it with a certificate and import it before installing.